# Does Node.js "express" come with "connect"?

Tags: javascript, node.js

After I install Express using npm....do I have to install "connect" if I want to use "connect"'s built-in stuff?

Answer (score 2):

Express is built on top of connect and as such has all of connect's built in stuff.

Answer (score 0):

npm will handle dependencies automatically.

So when you do `npm install express` it will install express an all the attached dependencies.